# Control noise in circuit to avoid disturbance in flow sensor reading

Tags: noise, esp32, ferrite-bead

I am controlling water pump and electro magnetic flow sensor ( YF-S201 ) by esp32. Flow meter affect while pump running. I disconnected flow sensor in my circuit for testing.
While pump start to running the flow reading rising. How flow readings generated while flow sensor disconnected. I tried capacitor 10uf inbetween esp32 and input relay. 1000uf capacitor connected in relay output. Esp32 Power supply from step down buck converter LM2596. Power source 12v 7.6 Amp battery. Pump 12v 4amp.can i use ferrite bead to control this.if ferrite bead can control this how can I attach ferrite bead in pcb. Need picture guidance for ferrite bead soldering. Thank you friends.[image]

Comment: Draw up a circuit that represents your situation. My first-order guess is when you disconnected the flow sensor, you GPIO is floating and picking up noise from the running pump.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.